# How to keep zookeeper run on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-zookeeper

I installed Zookeeper and Kafka on my ec2 instances, and they work well.

However, I wondered how to keep Zookeeper running on ec2.

I think if I make a real-time streaming service using Kafka, Zookeeper has to keep running state.

But it is shut down when I close a cli.

How to keep zookeeper run on ec2? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, until Zookeeper is fully removed from Kafka (target late 2022}, it stores important topic and broker information.

Ideally, you'd use a process supervisor like SystemD to (re)start, stop, and monitor the process. If you apt/yum install Confluent Platform, then it'll come with SystemD scripts for both Kafka and Zookeeper, so you wouldn't need to write your own.

And you'd use `zookeeper-server-start -daemon zookeeper.properties` to make it run in the background.

Or you can just use Amazon MSK and not worry about the infrastructure.

Comment: + 1 on going with MSK. you will offload the headache of managing Kafka. If you wan to start small they offer a 2 broker cluster with t3.smalls. One correction is In MSK, you can access the zookeeper nodes through the Zookeeper connection staring

Comment: Good to know you can access it, but it's generally recommended not to, unless you know what you are doing